# S3 Amplify React Native Storage.get(image) not display

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I try using hook on displaying my images from S3.

I keep received error 'source.uri should not be an empty string'

I dont know where am i missing here.

below is my code

```
const [img9, setImg9] = useState("");

const updateImgURL = async (img) => {
  console.log("into get s3");
  await Storage.get(img).then((data) => {
    setImg9(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  updateImgURL(m9_9_img);
}, []);

////////////////////////////////

        <Image
          style={{ height: 200, width: screenWidth / 3 + 20, borderWidth: 1 }}
          source={{
            uri: img9,
          }}
        />
```

fyi m9_9_img is a value that i get from previous screen object. I already do console log, it looks like the data has be set into the img9 but it still wont display. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the correct image url in the console log the issue occurs in the initial render.

When your component renders the first time the value of "img9" is empty so setting the empty value to the uri is throwing this error.

You will have to do a conditional render like below

```
(img9 && <Image
          style={{ height: 200, width: screenWidth / 3 + 20, borderWidth: 1 }}
          source={{
            uri: img9,
          }}
        />)
```

By doing this, the image component will only be rendered when the value for img9 is set, you can also have something like a loading flag and show loading indicator.

Comment: tq for ur solution...but now no error, image didnt display

Comment: Is the state updated with a valid image url ?, can you also hardcode the height and width and try ?

Comment: yes i already try hard code the height n width..stil empty box...but if i paste manually the S3 url(i get from console log)  inside the uri:'s3_url', the image will appear..

Comment: Where have you put the console.log ? can you put the state value in a text n see the value ? <Text>{img9}</Text>

Comment: try without the JSON.stringify when setting the state, I dont see anything wrong in the code

Comment: yes tq...i forgot....i remove the json.stringify...now its work like charm...tq very much

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 - Add a Temporary placeholder image in the state

```
const [img9, setImg9] = useState(require('../assets/images/placeholder.png'));
```

Solution 2 - render image view when image fetched from the s3 successfully.

```
    img9 ? <Image
      style={{ height: 200, width: screenWidth / 3 + 20, borderWidth: 1 }}
      source={{
        uri: img9,
      }}
    /> : null
```

Comment: tq for ur code...now no error but the image didnt display..          {img9 != "" ? (
            <>
              <Image
                style={{
                  height: 200,
                  width: screenWidth / 3 + 20,
                  borderWidth: 1,
                }}
                source={{ uri: img9 }}
              />
              <Text style={styles.subFont}>{img9}</Text>
            </>
          ) : (
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.subFont}>No Image Store{img9}</Text>
            </View>
          )}